# Update ng-grid with outside data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I have a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/h6eZJg?p=preview) with the following code

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Custom Plunker</title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/css/ng-grid.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div id="myGrid" class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
        <button onclick="hi()" type="button">hi</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'myData',
        showFilter: true,
        columnDefs: [{ field: "name", width: 120 , displayName : "Name" },
                    { field: "age", width: 120 },
                    { field: "birthday", width: 120 },
                    { field: "salary", width: 120 }]
    };
    $scope.myData = [];
});


function hi()
{
scope = angular.element($("#myGrid")).scope();
console.log( $("#myGrid") , angular.element($("#myGrid")) , scope );
if( scope )
scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.myData = [{ name: "Moroni", age: 50, birthday: "Oct 28, 1970", salary: "60,000" },
                    { name: "Tiancum", age: 43, birthday: "Feb 12, 1985", salary: "70,000" }];
    })
}
```

Now, when I click the button hi, I would expect to be able to set the content of the table to whatever I want to put there by calling apply() and setting myData. However it does not work.. What I am doing wrong?

Rationale: Basically I have a convoluted logic ( more complex than the built-in caching feature ) to check localStorage and then retrieve fresh data through a REST call if needed. Except, that it is three REST calls whose results need to be combined. Hence, it seems easiest for me to just be able to retrieve the right scope, assign the data and apply() after jumping through a number of hoops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT based on comment**

If you want to get the correct scope you just need to move the id to the controller element.

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl" id="myGrid">
```

Will get the correct scope.  Your plunkr works after only this change

**ORIGNAL ANSWER**

It appears from your plunkr that you are not actually getting the correct scope.

I forked your [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/U5D8Ml?p=preview) with a more standard way to get data in the grid.  I added an ng-click handler so that it can grab the scope of the controller.

```
<button ng-click="hi()" type="button">hi</button>
```

Then add the `hi` function to the controller

```
    $scope.hi = function(){
        $scope.myData = [{ name: "Moroni", age: 50, birthday: "Oct 28, 1970", salary: "60,000" },
                         { name: "Tiancum", age: 43, birthday: "Feb 12, 1985", salary: "70,000" }];
    };
```

Just have your function as part of the scope of your controller.  Then call the function with a button as you were to get the data into the grid.

You can easily replace this static data with data from a remote source

Comment: I'll try to formulate a response to that.  Any specific reason you can't work inside the controller?  This is the design pattern trying to save you from yourself